# Vim's SuperTab for emacs

Tags: completion

Vim has a plugin called [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) that uses the tab key to complete words in the current buffer (roughly speaking).

For example, if a buffer's contents are:

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.
```

Then typing `eval` and then pressing tab will complete `eval` to `evaluation`, since the latter word is already in the buffer.

---

I am looking for a emacs equivalent. I know of `hippie-expand`, but I do not quite like its behavior; sometimes, instead of completing just a word, it will try to complete an entire line.

Searching on the emacs-wiki, I found [smart-tab](https://github.com/genehack/smart-tab), which almost does what I want. The *only* rub is that, in the example above, it will complete `eval` to `evaluation.` instead of `evaluation`.

---

The question is the following:

1. Is there a direct SuperTab equivalent for emacs that I haven't discovered?
2. If not, is there a way to change smart-tab's behavior so that the extra period is not part of the completion?

Comment: I think you have already found it with smart-tab. I did not try it. But I think your only mistake was to use the scratch buffer for testing. Perhaps smart-tab completes symbols and the dot has the symbol category in lisp-evaluation mode (that one of *scratch*). Just use a normal text buffer. E.g., try `M-x text-mode` in the scratch buffer and afterwards try tab again.

Comment: Ah I see. Turning the scratch buffer to `text-mode` solves the problem. 

Thanks!

Comment: Please write that as an answer and accept it. So that this question displays as solved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with SuperTab, and it probably doesn't have an exact equivalent anyway, but rather similar features. Going by your description, I'd say you're looking for [`dabbrev-expand`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html#index-dabbrev_002dexpand), which is a built-in Emacs feature. The command is bound to `M-/` by default. It completes the current word from a pool that isn't exactly words in the current buffer, but close: it first looks backward from the current position, and then if it finds nothing it looks forward, and if it still finds nothing, it looks in other buffers. `M-/` completes the word in full; if you press is again, it gives you the next hit.

There's also `C-M-/` (`dabbrev-completion`), which completes the unambiguous part of the word.

`hippie-expand` is a sort of `dabbrev-expand` on steroids: it tries to guess your mind, but doesn't always succeed. `dabbrev-expand` always sticks to a word (according to the syntax rules of the current buffer). If `eval` expands to `evaluation.`, you must have tried it in a buffer where the syntax rules make `.` a symbol constituent, such as the `*scratch*` buffer as [Tobias](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2370/tobias) suggested (`*scratch*` uses Lisp syntax rules since its primary purpose is to let you type Lisp expressions that Emacs evaluates).

The smart-tab package invokes either `dabbrev-expand` or `hippie-expand` based on a configuration option. It doesn't provide a completion or expansion mechanism; what it does is to guess whether you mean to indent or to complete when you press Tab (whereas by default Emacs has completion and indentation on different keys).